# Output between two whitespaces

Tags: c++

I have this string: `System->ONDRASHEK: Nick aaasssddd není v žádné místnosti` and I need `aaasssddd` as output from string. Output is not the same each time. So it must be get from two whitespaces. I tried substr or split, but my knowledge of C++ is very poor.

I find this code:

```
   #include <string>
   #include <iostream>

   int main()
   {
    const std::string str = "System->ONDRASHEK: Nick aaasssddd není v žádné        místnosti";

    size_t pos = str.find(" ");
    if (pos == std::string::npos)
    return -1;

    pos = str.find(" ", pos + 1);
    if (pos == std::string::npos)
    return -1;

    std::cout << str.substr(pos, std::string::npos);
   }
```

But is not, what I need.

Comment: I assume you mean you get `Nick` and not that? Then just skip one whitespace and you're there. If something else, please explain more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want the third word from the given string.

You have find the second space, but your output is the sub-string from the second space to the end of the string.

Instead, you need to find the third space, and output the sub-string between the two spaces.

So here is the modification.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const std::string str = "System->ONDRASHEK: Nick aaasssddd není v žádné        místnosti";

    size_t pos = str.find(" ");
    size_t start;
    size_t end;
    if (pos == std::string::npos)
        return -1;

    pos = str.find(" ", pos + 1);
    if (pos == std::string::npos)
        return -1;

    start = pos + 1;

    pos = str.find(" ", pos + 1);
    if (pos == std::string::npos)
        return -1;

    end = pos;

    std::cout << str.substr(start, end - start) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: That is what exactly I need. Thank to you.

Answer (score 0):

please elaborate you question? you need substring between 2 white spaces ? if I am true, find first whitespace and then print string until you find another whitespace. you can use characters for that